# Black screen when fullscreening Twitch

Tags: video, google-chrome, flash, fullscreen

When I am watching a stream on twitch and activate fullscreen, the stream works properly in fullscreen. The issue occurs when I close fullscreen and try to open it again. The stream doesn't fullscreen and then the smaller (default) sized video player turns black.

The only solution that I have found is closing Chrome and reopening it.

I am using Chrome 31, GNOME 3.11.2, Flash 11.2 and Ubuntu 13.10